# Почему строка не массив в PHP?

Tags: php

Вначале хотел бы узнать почему строка не воспринимается как массив символов?

```
$v = 'string';
echo  count($v);
```

Показывает 1 вместо 6. Почему так?

Но в этом случае можно выкрутится с помощью `$array = str_split($v);` а что применить вместо str_split для русского текста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$v = 'string';
preg_match_all('/./su', $v, $v);
echo count($v);
```

Или так:

```
$v = 'string';
$v = preg_split('//', $v, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
echo count($v);
```

Comment: Второй да, а первый что-то тоже 1 показывает http://ideone.com/RqrIJ5

Comment: по моему, вопрос звучал "почему", а не как сделать. Можно и str_len($v), но...

Comment: @RoboNoob, я читал. Там ещё от кодировки страницы зависит, как будет показывать

Comment: @Ep1demic strlen как вы юникод посчитаете? Нука я на вас посмотрю )))

Comment: @Yuri извиняюсь, всё правильно первый вариант показывает 1 потому что многомерный же, во втором массиве там всё как надо

Comment: @RoboNoob а вы это ради подсчета количества символом затеять хотите?

Comment: @tutankhamun нет конечно что бы получить каждый символ по отдельности. Кстати предположим вы не можете использовать mb_strlen какой способ подсчёта длины строки вы тогда изберёте?

Comment: @RoboNoob А почему не могу? За неуплату отключили? :) Если серьезно, то в продакшн с велосипедом и не полезу, а чисто "для интереса" в utf8 посчитал бы байты, у которых старшие два бита не `10`